# Access DB outside an activity on android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to access my DB outside an activity and I get an error.
My architecture is having a wrapper for the DB, so when I want to display something in the activity I just create a class and take the information from it.
for example I want to create a HUMAN class that will access the DB through the db adapter class that I created. in the adapter class I return a cursor to the relevant row/s.
I tried doing so using startManagingCursor and I get an error saying it is undefined, when I try using this method in activity everything seems fine.

basically please try and give me an example of how to handle my DB in the right way.
I have a very big DB and I thought that creating a class for each table on the DB and than let the table get it's information is the right way, but I am not sure how to do that.
what I thought is lets create an instance of human with the id of 3 than in the constructor of Human (which is not an activity) go to the db get the information in a cursor and save all the information in the data members.

Thank you